# Fetch mulitple values using Jquery post getting undefined value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Below is my jquery ajax method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#c_select').change(function(){
           var  one = 10;
           var  two = 20;
           var  three = 30;
           var  four = 40;  
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'getvalues.php',
            dataType: JSON,
            success:function(resp){
            alert(resp.first);
            }   
            error:function(resp){

            alert(resp.first);

           }
        }); 
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Below given file is where i get the values (PHP File)

```
    <?php
       $output =  array('first'=>'Steven',
                     'last'=>'Spielberg',
                     'address'=>'1234 Unlisted Drive');
      echo json_encode($output,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
   ?>
```

success part is not getting executed i am getting undefined error

Comment: I'm not able to see any data being passed by the ajax?

Comment: Since you are sending data in json encoded format. Try JSON.parse(resp) and then try accessing data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following code, it should work

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('#c_select').change(function() {
     var one = 10;
     var two = 20;
     var three = 30;
     var four = 40;
     $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: 'getvalues.php',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(resp) {
         alert(resp.first);
       },
       error: function(resp) {

       }
     });
   });
 });
```

Comment: got it i had used  dataType: JSON now i have changed it to dataType: 'json' its working fine but i dint get what is the problem using dataType: JSON

Comment: @001 The error is your dataType value. You used the JavaScript Object `JSON`, but the property only accepts a string (xml, json, script, or html).